# Search a unique list and search a larger list to set dictionary with keys of binary values

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy, search

I would like to search a list of unique values and create a dictionary with those unique values as keys, and a binary list for whether those values occur.

I have successfully solved this, but would like a more efficient solution. This solution performs a high amount of operations for a search list of size 1000, 10000, and 1000000.

This code is fully reproducible.

```
import numpy as np

# Create random array, len(10), of integers 1-5

array_to_search = np.array(np.random.randint(0,5,(1,10)))
array_to_search = array_to_search.flatten()

#array_to_search = [0 3 0 0 0 2 1 3 3 0]

# Extract each unique value from array_to_search

array_of_unique_values = np.unique(array_to_search)

# array_of_unique_values = [0 1 2 3]

# Create a dictionary of unique values
output = dict.fromkeys(array_of_unique_values)

# Declare lists as values to the dictionary

output = { k : [] for k in array_of_unique_values}

# For each value in unique values, search the larger list and set the dictionary
# value to a 1 if found, 0 if not found.

for i in array_of_unique_values:
    for j in array_to_search:
        if i == j:
            output[i].append(1) 
        else:
            output[i].append(0)

output = {0: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
          1: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
          2: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          3: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]}
```

Comment: You could write `{i:array_to_search == i for i in np.unique(array_to_search)}`, but why do you need this? It seems wasteful to allocate all these arrays of Booleans when you could just write `array_to_search == i` when you need one of them. Please tell us more about your real problem — if we knew more about it, we might be able to spot a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` with broadcasting is the most straightforward solution:

```
array_to_search = np.array(np.random.randint(0,5,(1,10))).ravel()
array_of_unique_values = np.unique(array_to_search)

# Creates the binary vectors
matches = array_of_unique_values[:, None] == array_to_search

# Converts to dict
output = dict(zip(array_of_unique_values, matches))
```

You can also set `return_indices` flag to `True` in `np.unique` and use these to create the table:

```
array_to_search = np.array(np.random.randint(0,5,(1,10))).ravel()
array_of_unique_values, indices = np.unique(array_to_search, return_inverse=True)
matches = np.zeros((array_of_unique_values.size, array_to_search.size), dtype=bool)
matches[indices, np.arange(array_to_search.size)] = True
output = dict(zip(array_of_unique_values, matches))
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] it to explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that everyone can learn from your thought process.

Answer (score -1):

If you put it in a Pandas Series, then you can use `get_dummies` to get a DataFrame containing the data you want. If you want it as a dictionary of lists, then you can just convert it with `output = {col:list(df[col]) for col in df.columns}`